# What do `:` and `?` mean in `{:?}`

Tags: rust

I use `{:?}` for debugging purpose.

But I don't know (or maybe I just don't remember) what's the meaning of `:` and `?` individually.  Is there any reference for this?

Comment: Of course there is documentation. And very detailed one. Right where it should be: in the [std::fmt](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) module.

Comment: Ok maybe I should update my answer. My question was not about "how to use?" but about : "`?` means...". Not sure it's clear enough, sorry about that.

Comment: The documentation [does say](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-traits) what the `?`, and other formatting characters, mean, too.

Comment: @rap-2-h it sounds like you could ask this for just about anything in any language: Why pick `{}` for formatting at all? Why use `()` when calling a method? Why use `<>` for generics? Why use `$foo` for variable references? Why is the symbol `2` used to represent `1 + 1`? And so on. Ultimately, the answer will boil down to something unglamorous like "because they symbol was easy to type and unused" or "because another language did it".

Comment: BTW, this is missing from the syntax index in the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:` separates parameter index from the format specification. The `{}` may contain parameter index, e.g. `{0}`, `{1}` etc. If you want to specify format, you must introduce it with `:`, e.g. `{0:?}`. And `?` specifies, that formatting should be done using the `std::fmt::Debug` trait instead of the default `std::fmt::Display` (other characters specify other traits, e.g. `x` for `Hex`, `e` for `LowerExp` etc.).

Comment: Ok thanks. BTW I don't understand why a question mark is used for "debug". In other words, I was looking for an answer about why choose `?` and not `anything else`? (not sure to understand the relation between "debug" and "question mark")

Comment: But maybe it's just a dumb question, sorry I can't control my mind (and my hands)!

Comment: @rap-2-h: Well, an unused symbol was needed, `?` was unused... and then again, when debugging you're often asking yourself "What value does it have??" so I find the question mark quite appropriate.